# Wordpress Multisite installation-generated .htaccess fails

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

My first (fresh) Wordpress installation and its a multisite one. Everything went smoothly until Wordpress installation process generated the following code to put in a .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # uploaded files
    RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Which promptly made the entire site unusable by presenting me with a 403 Forbidden error. Now as far as I can tell everything should be ok with proper directories and file permissions. Plus I installed it into root, etc.

I've been hunting for a solution on Google and found that (for this particular problem) some hosts might require wrapping the entire .htaccess in:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.so>
    ...
    </IfModule>
```

Which now works on the root index (index.php) and shows the site, but fails as soon as I click any of the test posts (change the address).

So I guess I'm stuck and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does apache has permissions to read .htaccess?? .htaccess must have 644 permissions

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your site doesn't have mod_rewrite loaded. It should be in your server config and looks something like this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Additionally, make sure that the wordpress installed under a user/group/permissions that is readable by apache.